# Is "the" missed?

Tags: definite-article

In this example:

> > [You need to be able to convey the subtle nuances of meaning of each word.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/nuance)

`meaning` does not have `the`. Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly OK without 'the'. The expression "nuances of meaning" is quite common.

Comment: The lack of "the" before "meaning" isn't any of that sentence's problems, like, for example, a lack of coherency and that second "of" are.

Comment: Hmm. This might be better: "You need to be able to convey each word's subtle nuances of meaning."